# Return only groups that have correct combination of values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to filter out any group that does not have some desired values in a column. Here here I want to return the data.frame where a `grp` has both "var1" and "var2" in `x`. I can do it with `summarise` and `paste` but that feels a bit clunky.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

dat <- tibble(
  x = c("var1", "var2", "var1"),
  grp = c("grp1", "grp1", "grp2")
)


dat_summary <- dat %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(both_vars = paste(x, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  filter(both_vars == "var1, var2")

dat_summary$grp
#> [1] "grp1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `filter` to filter the grp s having `all` the 'var1', 'var2' in the 'x' column and then `pull` the `distinct` elements of 'grp'

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(all(c("var1", "var2") %in% x)) %>% 
  distinct(grp) %>% 
  pull(grp)
[1] "grp1"
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
 Reduce(intersect, with(subset(dat, x %in% c("var1", "var2")),  split(grp, x)))
[1] "grp1"
```